# Export Product CSV with Tier Price

Tags: product, export, dataflow, tierprice

I would like to create a CSV with product default data and also tier price.

Is it possible to use DataFlow ?

In alternative I would like to use a custom script with direct query to DB, can you help me create this query ?

Comment: I don't know how it is possible to use DataFlow but with direct PHP it is no problem. You just have to join into the `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` table and have the `customer_group_id` and the `website_id` in the ON statement. Then you get a lot rows for every product with the different prices for the groups/website and the qty.

Comment: Did you try creating a product using tiered pricing then export that product using Dataflows? I would try that then use it as an template.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the script I use:

```
    //Magento export tier price of all product to csv
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');

header("Content-type:text/octect-stream");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=data.csv");

$tableName = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
 ->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_tier_price');
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$products   = $product->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($storeId)->getAllIds();

$fieldname = array("store","websites","attribute_set","type","sku","name","tier_price_website","tier_price_customer_group","tier_price_qty","tier_price_price");
print stripslashes(implode(',',$fieldname)) . "\n";
foreach($products as $productid)
{
$existingTierPrice = $product ->load($productid)->tier_price;
$sku = $product->getSku();
$name = $product->getName();
foreach($existingTierPrice as $key=>$value)
{
$tierarray = array("admin","base","Default","simple",$sku,$name,"all","all",$value['price_qty'],$value['price']);
print stripslashes(implode(',',$tierarray)) . "\n";
}
}
```

Courtesy of http://developerafroz.blogspot.com/2011/05/magento-export-tier-price.html